# Is it secure that we call an arbitrary target function in a contract through a proxy contract?

Tags: proxy, solidity, call

I am designing a useful contract as follows with good intentions. However, I'm curious if there's a way to maliciously attack the proxy contract or MyApp contract. What kind of attacks are possible?

Since the MyApp contract owns tokens, there could be a problem if MyApp directly calls an arbitrary contract (because the arbitrary function could be a transfer of the token), so I placed a CallerProxy in the middle. CallerProxy is a contract without assets.

```
contract CallerProxy {
    address public app;
    constructor(address app_) {
        app = app_;
    }
    function callByProxy(address target, bytes memory data) external returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        require(msg.sender == app, "only my app can call this");

        return target.call(data);
    }
}

contract MyApp {
    CallerProxy callerProxy;
    constructor() {
        callerProxy = new CallerProxy(address(this));
    }
    function callArbitrary(address target, bytes memory data) external {
        (bool success, bytes memory ret) = callerProxy.callByProxy(target, data);
    }
}

contract OtherApp {
    uint256 public count;
    function increase(uint256 inc) external {
        count += inc;
    }
}

...
// expected use case
uint256 inc = 100;
bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(OtherApp.increase, inc);
myApp.callArbitrary(address(otherApp), data);

...
// an unintended abuse case?
```

Since the Proxy has no assets, I expect that it will not be susceptible to attacks.